# Access private variables in injected method - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Question is at the end**

What am I trying to do is :

1. Inject property to created object and set it instead of a variable (success)
2. Inject method (let's call it METHOD) to created object, object had no such method before (success)
3. Call public another method from property using self (success)
4. Call METHOD from property using self (success)
5. Get private class variable from METHOD using self (**failure**)

Now, here is some code:

```python
from types import MethodType
def add_property(instance, name, method):
    cls = type(instance)
    cls = type(cls.__name__, (cls,), {})
    cls.__perinstance = True
    instance.__class__ = cls
    setattr(cls, name, property(method))

def add_variable(instance, name, init_value = 0 ):
    setattr(type(instance), name, init_value)

class Simulation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.finished = False
        self.__hidden = -10

    def someloop(self):
        while not self.finished:
            self.__private_method()

    def __private_method(self):
        pass 

    def public_method(self):
        pass

def mocked_method(self):
    print(type(self))
    print(self.__dict__)
    print(self.__hidden)

def finished(self):

    print("Execute finished",type(self))
    self.public_method()
    self.mocked_update()
    return True


simulation = Simulation() 
add_property(simulation, "finished", finished)
add_variable(simulation, "count_finished", 0)
simulation.mocked_update = MethodType(mocked_method, simulation)
simulation.someloop()
```

What code produced (those prints):

```
Execute finished '<class '__main__.Simulation'>
<class '__main__.Simulation'>
{'finished': False, '_Simulation__hidden': -10, 'mocked_update': <bound method mocked_method of <__main__.Simulation object at 0x030D2F10>>}
(...)
AttributeError: 'Simulation' object has no attribute '__hidden'
```

As you can see self is what it should be (simulation class), it was properly injected and yet it doesn't work.
In case you are wondering :

```
print(self._Simulation__hidden)
```

obviously works inside mocked_update.

Hence my question : **Is there any chance for me to access this variable using self?**

**Motivation**

Since there was a question in the comments section:

This does not serve any real purpose, it is just an experiment.

Comment: I don't understand. What can we assume, that you have the name of the private method? What exactly do you want to do, and why does `self._Simulation_hidden` not work for you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just an experiment, it serves no real purpose. I am just curious if this can be accomplished.

Comment: Sorry, *now* I understand what you are trying to do. Sorry, I was confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name mangling of "private" members is strictly done within class definitions.  To achieve the desired purpose, which is to have `self.__hidden` translated to `self._Simulation_hidden` you need simply define it *within an appropriately named class*.

For example:

```
def make_mocked_method():
    class Simulation:
        # this is your code, but now its inside a class stanza so '__' will be mangled
        def mocked_method(self):
            print(type(self))
            print(self.__dict__)
            print(self.__hidden)

    return Simulation.mocked_method
```

Now `mocked_method` will access the desired attribute correctly:

```
simulation.mocked_update = MethodType(make_mocked_method(), simulation)
simulation.someloop()
```

gives:

```
<class '__main__.Simulation'>
{'finished': False, 'mocked_update': <bound method make_mocked_method.<locals>.Simulation.mocked_method of <__main__.Simulation object at 0x101c00a58>>, '_Simulation__hidden': -10}
-10
```

#### Extension

This relies on us hard coding the name of the class we're adding the method to (`Simulation`).   To avoid that we can instead use an `exec`:

```
def make_mocked_method(cls):
    txt = """class {}:
        def mocked_method(self):
            print(type(self))
            print(self.__dict__)
            print(self.__hidden)
    """.format(cls.__name__)
    ns = {}
    exec(txt, ns)
    return ns[cls.__name__].mocked_method
```

Unfortunately here the function we wish to add must be defined as text, it can't be some already defined arbitrary function object.  (That might possibly be solved by using `inspect` to find its source and then recompiling that source within a class stanza using `exec` (and judicious choice of `globals`).

Comment: This is clever, but if you have to know the name of the class to write the class defnition, you might as well just write  `self._Simulation__hidden`, it seems. I didn't realize names don't get mangled when you do: `A = type('A', (object,), {'__hidden':42})`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's certainly not to be recommended ... this was just answering the question of whether "it can be done"!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I wouldn't think that one can do this!